# Windows 10 Taskbar Issue with Open Windows Mapping to Wrong Taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar

I am trying to use the option in Windows 10 where an open window only appears on the taskbar of the monitor it's open in. In the taskbar settings its called Show Taskbar Buttons on the "Taskbar where window is open". It use to work for me but its recently stopped working. Now all open windows map only to my main taskbar and not the monitor it's open in. I've tried the usual, restarts, updating, toggling settings, etc but haven't been able to fix the problem. Has anyone fixed a problem like this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've found, it seems as if the problem is related to the programs auto-starting in the previous window they were open. If you move a program to the main monitor, and then back to where they were, the taskbar will properly reflect the windows of the programs.

It seems that Windows 10 likes to remember which window you had the program open on, and even what sizing and position. Unfortunately, it seems to not recognize that it is on another monitor, and defaults to the first taskbar.

As a workaround until Microsoft fixes this, you can select your window, press the Windows Key + the left/right arrow key (whichever direction your main monitor is) and then back the other direction. (you may need to press multiple times, depending on whether the window is maximized or not).

After toggling the program from the main back to the monitor it was on, your taskbar will properly show the programs on the respective monitors.